# fadeIn in IE works bad, make it pop in if in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Im using jquery and I use fadeIn to fade in some images. However these are transparant pngs and they look really bad in older Internet explorer versions when they are fading. I wonder if there's a way that will make the stuff thats going to fade instead just appear if the visitor is using an older IE version?

Comment: Why do you care about older versions of IE? (IE 6 is out!) http://ie6funeral.com/

Comment: Rumplin - 9.7% of the world still use IE6 (http://www.ie6countdown.com/)

Comment: Actually... no. Not nice workarounds out there

Comment: @Thomas Clayson I keep using this, so less and less users use IE6 http://ie6update.com/

Comment: And actually it's 3.1% :D ! http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201008-201108

Comment: @Rumplin yeah its a good idea. Honestly though, I've seen people, even now, buying Windows XP netbooks/computers/laptops and such and just using IE6. IMO its their fault. If you buy frosted glass lenses for your spectacles you can't expect to see things properly, unfortunately it doesn't quite work like that. Until useage is <1% I reckon we're still going to have to grin and bear it. (And by that time it'll be IE7 and IE8 we're bitching about)

Comment: But the fade actually works bad even in IE7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before starting the fade, just check for `JQuery.support.opacity`.

If you want to do it transparently, write your own condidational fade plugin, that does the check, and then either fades or pops, depending on support.

`JQuery.support.opacity` should return false on IE.

Comment: But that will NOT run the effect... or?

Comment: it will NOT run the effect on browsers that don't support opacity. That seems correct to me. Graceful degradation FTW :)